# Python Initializing and typing at the same time

Tags: python, initialization, typing

Can I initialize an empty dictionary and typing it at the same time?

For example something like that, however I don't think this is proper.

```
self.groups: Dict[str, Group]
self.groups = dict()
```

Comment: `groups` should be type annotated at the class level, to follow python typing convetions, although it isn't required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, simply insert the type hint after the variable name in the assignment.

```
self.groups: Dict[str, Group] = dict()
```